# c# tcp How can i get exacly amount of bytes that are recived?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

```
if(client.Available > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[18000];
                    client.GetStream().Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(stream);
                    if (!Shown)
                    {
                        Shown = true;
                        ssViewer.Show();
                        ssViewer.UpdateImage(bit);
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    PrintToConsole("There was an error in data " + ex.ToString(), ConsoleColor.Red);
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

So problem is when i do this it gives me error "Parameter is not valid",i think its because there are less bytes in array that it is to read.Is there a way to know how many bytes are there to read from recivedBuffer?

Comment: `Stream.Read` returns the amount of bytes read. And yes, for TCP you're not guaranteed to receive all bytes with one call to `Read`, you'll have to loop.

Comment: @BiesiGrr it returns amount of how man are bytes were read(18000)

Comment: @BiesiGrr could you give me example of that loop?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood that question.. The sender needs to tell the receiver how many bytes it is going to send before sending the actual data.

Comment: it depends of the protocol which is implemented between sender and receiver. Many protocol use a header, which has a fix size of bytes, and it contains the amount of byte that must be wait for. Another way is send messages with a fixes size; in this way you will know how many bytes wait for and how many bytes send.

Answer (score 2):

Read until there is no bytes left

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; // read in chunks of 2KB
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    //do something with data in buffer, up to the size indicated by bytesRead
}

// yay no bytes left
```

Answer (score 0):

`Read` returns the number of bytes read:

```
var bytesRead = client.GetStream().Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

so you could use the following to construct the `MemoryStream`:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes.Take(bytesRead).ToArray());
```

It's worth noting that you're dealing with a `Stream` which means you may not receive all of your data in one shot.

That is to say, if I send "ABC" and "DEF" as two separate messages, I could receive it in any number of ways (some examples below):

- ABCDEF (1 "receive" event)
- ABC, DEF (2 "receive" events)
- A, BCDE, F (3 "receive" events)
- ABCDE, F (2 "receive" events)
- A, B, C, D, E, F (6 "receive" events).

Typically people will send an indicator of the size first, read that out, and then use that to determine when their full "message" has been received.

Comment: @Saruman It's this or my headache of a MongoDB aggregation :-)

Comment: Dear downvoter: I answered the question asked ("Is there a way to know how many bytes are there to read from recivedBuffer?") and provided accurate information about how receiving data works as a bonus. Not sure if your downvote was justified.